# How to unregister a DLL?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I know I can register a DLL using `REGSRV32 NAME.DLL` but I ran a wrong `FOR` loop alongside `regsrv32` which registered all DLL's in my **Windows 7** partition and crashed my system. I now need to unregister all those DLL's and reregister the correct DLL's. Please tell me the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the /u switch: `REGSRV32 /u NAME.DLL`

Comment: Is there a method to reregister at one go?